# Change the encoding of a .csv file before MySQL import

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I create a CSV file with an automated VB script of an Excel file. The file is encoded with `latin_1`. To import this file correctly into my MySQL database I need to convert the encoding of the file to `UTF8`.

It works if I save the file manually to UTF8, but I would like to have that automated with PHP.

The direction is *XLS -> CSV -> MYSql*. Everything runs on windows.

Comment: Are you have xls or csv originally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert the encoding of any text file from any encoding to UTF-8. Note that it will not work with an XLS file; you'd have to convert it to CSV first:

```
$pathToFile = '...';
$original = file_get_contents($pathToFile);
$originalEncoding = mb_detect_encoding($original);
$converted = mb_convert_encoding($original, 'UTF-8', $originalEncoding);
file_put_contents($pathToFile, $converted);
```

If you don't want to overwrite your original file, specify a different first argument for `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: There is an open source library know as [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that can parse XLS files without the need to convert to CSV manually.